# Get element that called $(window).bind("mousewheel") function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a mousewheel function in jQuery bound to the window element which controls a slider.

Now, I also have a scrollable `ul` item where, on scrolling, I don't want to change the slider as well.

Can I combine the `window.bind` function with the `$(this)` function to not change slider when scrolled within the `ul`?

Here is the code for slider change on scroll

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
   if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      //INCREASE SLIDER ON SCROLL UP
   } else {
  //DECREASE SLIDER ON SCROLL UP        
   }
});
```

Where I am increasing the slider or decreasing it, I want to check if this mousewheel action has been called in the `ul` element. If yes, then slider shouldn't change.

Comment: `if($(e.target).closest('ul').length)` ???

Comment: e.target https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: Do explain how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question, use:

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
   if($(e.target).closest('ul').length) return;
   if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      //INCREASE SLIDER ON SCROLL UP
   } else {
  //DECREASE SLIDER ON SCROLL UP        
   }
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer, once again.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: This won't work on IE 8. The event will never be fired.

Comment: @Alvaro that's correct but not relevant to OP question so why the downvote?

Comment: @A.Wolff yep fine. You are right. Just edit the answer so I can change my vote again.

Comment: @Alvaro that's ok, i won't cry for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way to make it cross browser:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false); //IE9, Chrome, Safari, Oper
    document.addEventListener("wheel", MouseWheelHandler, false); //Firefox
} else {
    document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler); //IE 6/7/8
}


function MouseWheelHandler(){
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.deltaY || -e.detail)));

    //scrolling down?
    if (delta < 0) {

    }

    //scrolling up?
    else {

    }
}
```

Comment: @A.Wolff not really. It doesn't work on IE 8 if you try it with `$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {`

Comment: I tested it, you are correct but this doesn't answer OP's question at all